# WSL: change home directory to Windows world

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I already use `HOME=c:\home` as my home directory (for Cygwin).

How can I point WSL to that directory?

I edited `/etc/passwd` file replacing home dir to `/mnt/c/home`. With `bash -i`  `~/.bashrc` settings are picked up.

Is it correct to move home directory outside of WSL world?

Comment: @gavenkoa I think you can create a symbolic link but you would be better off moving your old home files to the new home for safety as it's hidden from Windows programs which can damage Linux files if they "touch them".